# Reviewing my shader class for efficient use

Tags: c++, opengl, shaders

Im just trying to setup my shader function in a class in a way that would make me work with it easier and in a more understandable way.

In Shader.h:

```
#pragma once
#include"Includes.h"
#include<unordered_map>

namespace GAME
{
    enum class Shader_Type
    {
        NONE = -1,
        VERTEX = 0,
        FRAGMENT = 1,
        GEOMETRY = 2
    };

    class Shader
    {
    private:
        std::map<Shader_Type, std::string>m_Data;
        Shader_Type type;
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m_UniformLocationCache;
    public:
        unsigned int Program_id;
    private:
        unsigned int Compiler(unsigned int type, const std::string& source);
        void Check_errors(unsigned int* id, unsigned int type);
        void Create_shader();

    public:

        Shader();
        ~Shader();

        Shader(const Shader& e);
        Shader& operator=(const Shader& e);
        Shader(Shader&& e)noexcept;
        Shader& operator=(Shader&& e)noexcept;
        Shader* operator-> () { return this; }

        operator Shader* () { return this; }
        Shader* Clone() { return new Shader(*this); }


        void Bind() const;
        void Unbind() const;

        void Reset();
        void Init(std::string vertexShader = "", std::string fragmentshader = "", std::string Geometryshader = "");

        unsigned int GetUniformLocation(const std::string& name);



        //uniforms

        void Setuniform1f(const std::string& name, float v1);
        void Setuniform2f(const std::string& name, float v1, float v2);
        void Setuniform3f(const std::string& name, float v1, float v2, float v3);
        void Setuniform4f(const std::string& name, float v1, float v2, float v3, float v4);

        void Setuniform1i(const std::string& name, int v1);
        void Setuniform2i(const std::string& name, int v1, int v2);
        void Setuniform3i(const std::string& name, int v1, int v2, int v3);
        void Setuniform4i(const std::string& name, int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4);

        void Setuniform1d(const std::string& name, double v1);
        void Setuniform2d(const std::string& name, double v1, double v2);
        void Setuniform3d(const std::string& name, double v1, double v2, double v3);
        void Setuniform4d(const std::string& name, double v1, double v2, double v3, double v4);



        void Setuniform1fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec1 v);
        void Setuniform2fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec2 v);
        void Setuniform3fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec3 v);
        void Setuniform4fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec4 v);

        void Setuniform1iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec1 v);
        void Setuniform2iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec2 v);
        void Setuniform3iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec3 v);
        void Setuniform4iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec4 v);

        void Setuniform1dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec1 v);
        void Setuniform2dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec2 v);
        void Setuniform3dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec3 v);
        void Setuniform4dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec4 v);



        void SetUniformMat2fv(const std::string& name, int count, GLboolean transpose, glm::mat2 value);
        void SetUniformMat3fv(const std::string& name, int count, GLboolean transpose, glm::mat3 value);
        void SetUniformMat4fv(const std::string& name, int count, GLboolean transpose, glm::mat4 value);



    };


}
```

`#include"Includes.h"` is the header where I kept all includes of gl and other required classes

In Shader.cpp:

```
#include "Shader.h"
namespace GAME
{
    Shader::Shader()
        :Program_id(0), type(Shader_Type::NONE)
    {
    }
    Shader::~Shader()
    {
    }

    Shader::Shader(const Shader& e)
    {
        this->m_Data = e.m_Data;
        this->m_UniformLocationCache = e.m_UniformLocationCache;
        this->Program_id = e.Program_id;
        this->type = Shader_Type(e.type);
    }

    Shader& Shader::operator=(const Shader& e)
    {
        this->m_Data = e.m_Data;
        this->m_UniformLocationCache = e.m_UniformLocationCache;
        this->Program_id = e.Program_id;
        this->type = Shader_Type(e.type);
        return *this;
    }

    Shader::Shader(Shader&& e) noexcept
    {
        this->m_Data = std::move(e.m_Data);
        this->m_UniformLocationCache = std::move(e.m_UniformLocationCache);
        this->Program_id =std::move( e.Program_id);
        this->type = std::move(Shader_Type(e.type));
    }

    Shader& Shader::operator=(Shader&& e) noexcept
    {
        this->m_Data = std::move(e.m_Data);
        this->m_UniformLocationCache = std::move(e.m_UniformLocationCache);
        this->Program_id = std::move(e.Program_id);
        this->type = std::move(Shader_Type(e.type));
        return *this;
    }

    void Shader::Bind() const
    {
        glUseProgram(Program_id);
    }
    void Shader::Unbind() const
    {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }


    void Shader::Reset()
    {
        this->type = Shader_Type::NONE;
        this->Program_id = 0;
        this->m_UniformLocationCache.clear();
        this->m_Data.clear();
    }
    void Shader::Init(std::string vertexShader, std::string fragmentshader, std::string Geometryshader)
    {
        m_Data[Shader_Type::VERTEX] = vertexShader;
        m_Data[Shader_Type::FRAGMENT] = fragmentshader;
        m_Data[Shader_Type::GEOMETRY] = Geometryshader;

        Create_shader();
        Unbind();
    }

    unsigned int Shader::GetUniformLocation(const std::string& name)
    {
        if (m_UniformLocationCache.find(name) != m_UniformLocationCache.end())
        {
            return m_UniformLocationCache[name];
        }
        int location = glGetUniformLocation(Program_id, name.c_str());
        if (location == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Warning! Uniform " << name << " is unused or not found or does no exist!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
            m_UniformLocationCache[name] = location;
        return location;
    }

    void Shader::Create_shader()
    {
        Program_id = glCreateProgram();

        if (m_Data[Shader_Type::VERTEX] != "")
        {
            unsigned int vs = Compiler(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, m_Data[Shader_Type::VERTEX]);
            glAttachShader(Program_id, vs);
            glDeleteShader(vs);
        }
        if (m_Data[Shader_Type::FRAGMENT] != "")
        {
            unsigned int fs = Compiler(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, m_Data[Shader_Type::FRAGMENT]);
            glAttachShader(Program_id, fs);
            glDeleteShader(fs);
        }
        if (m_Data[Shader_Type::GEOMETRY] != "")
        {
            unsigned int gs = Compiler(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, m_Data[Shader_Type::GEOMETRY]);
            glAttachShader(Program_id, gs);
            glDeleteShader(gs);
        }

        glLinkProgram(Program_id);
        glValidateProgram(Program_id);

    }

    unsigned int Shader::Compiler(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
    {
        unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
        const char* src = source.c_str();
        glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(id);

        Check_errors(&id, type);

        return id;
    }

    void Shader::Check_errors(unsigned int* id, unsigned int type)
    {
        int result;
        glGetShaderiv(*id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
        if (result == GL_FALSE)
        {
            int length;
            glGetShaderiv(*id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
            glGetShaderInfoLog(*id, length, &length, message);
            std::cout << "Failed to compile ";
            switch (type)
            {
            case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
                std::cout << "vertex";
                break;
            case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
                std::cout << "fragment";
                break;
            case GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER:
                std::cout << "geometry";
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "unknown";
                break;
            }
            std::cout << " shader!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " Error:" << message << std::endl;
            glDeleteShader(*id);
            id = 0;
        }

    }





    void Shader::Setuniform1f(const std::string& name, float v1)
    {
        glUniform1f(GetUniformLocation(name), v1);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform2f(const std::string& name, float v1, float v2)
    {
        glUniform2f(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform3f(const std::string& name, float v1, float v2, float v3)
    {
        glUniform3f(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2, v3);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform4f(const std::string& name, float v1, float v2, float v3, float v4)
    {
        glUniform4f(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2, v3, v4);
    }

    void Shader::Setuniform1i(const std::string& name, int v1)
    {
        glUniform1i(GetUniformLocation(name), v1);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform2i(const std::string& name, int v1, int v2)
    {
        glUniform2i(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform3i(const std::string& name, int v1, int v2, int v3)
    {
        glUniform3i(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2, v3);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform4i(const std::string& name, int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4)
    {
        glUniform4i(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2, v3, v4);
    }

    void Shader::Setuniform1d(const std::string& name, double v1)
    {
        glUniform1d(GetUniformLocation(name), v1);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform2d(const std::string& name, double v1, double v2)
    {
        glUniform2d(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform3d(const std::string& name, double v1, double v2, double v3)
    {
        glUniform3d(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2, v3);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform4d(const std::string& name, double v1, double v2, double v3, double v4)
    {
        glUniform4d(GetUniformLocation(name), v1, v2, v3, v4);
    }

    void Shader::Setuniform1fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec1 v)
    {
        glUniform1fv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform2fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec2 v)
    {
        glUniform2fv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform3fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec3 v)
    {
        glUniform3fv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform4fv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::fvec4 v)
    {
        glUniform4fv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }

    void Shader::Setuniform1iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec1 v)
    {
        glUniform1iv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform2iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec2 v)
    {
        glUniform2iv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform3iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec3 v)
    {
        glUniform3iv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform4iv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::ivec4 v)
    {
        glUniform4iv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }

    void Shader::Setuniform1dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec1 v)
    {
        glUniform1dv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform2dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec2 v)
    {
        glUniform2dv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform3dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec3 v)
    {
        glUniform3dv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }
    void Shader::Setuniform4dv(const std::string& name, int count, glm::dvec4 v)
    {
        glUniform4dv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, &v[0]);
    }

    void Shader::SetUniformMat2fv(const std::string& name, int count, GLboolean transpose, glm::mat2 value)
    {
        glUniformMatrix2fv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, transpose, &value[0][0]);
    }
    void Shader::SetUniformMat3fv(const std::string& name, int count, GLboolean transpose, glm::mat3 value)
    {
        glUniformMatrix3fv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, transpose, &value[0][0]);
    }
    void Shader::SetUniformMat4fv(const std::string& name, int count, GLboolean transpose, glm::mat4 value)
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(GetUniformLocation(name), count, transpose, &value[0][0]);
    }

}
```

Is this enough for using in normal programming or do i need to make some changes to make it more usable and efficient? Any helpful review would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Various suggestions:

- Use the OpenGL types (e.g. `GLuint`, `GLint`) for the variables that need them. It's more portable, and the purpose of the variables is clearer.
- Don't store the shader source inside the shader. We don't need it after compiling the shader.
- It doesn't look like the `type` member variable is actually used (and it doesn't make sense as programs are made up of shader objects of various different types).
- The `Program_id` shouldn't be public, as the user shouldn't be able to change it directly. Add a getter function for it.
- We should destroy the shader program with `glDeleteProgram` when we're done with it (i.e. in the destructor).
- Copying a shader program doesn't really make sense from an OpenGL point of view... there's no way to copy OpenGL shaders or shader objects. So I'd suggest `=delete`ing the copy constructor and copy assignment operator, and only supporting move operations.
- We don't need `operator->` or `operator*` or the `Clone()` function (and they don't really make sense).
- I don't think there's any point in caching uniform locations in a map keyed by a `std::string`. The driver will be doing more or less the exact same look-up when `glGetUniformLocation()` is called.
- Consider having separate "ShaderObject" and "ShaderProgram" classes. This might make loading assets easier later on (shader objects can be used by multiple programs), and it's closer to the OpenGL model.

---

Some other things about the code:

```
    if (m_UniformLocationCache.find(name) != m_UniformLocationCache.end())
    {
        return m_UniformLocationCache[name];
    }
```

This does two searches. Once when calling `.find()`, and the other in `[name]`. We should use the return value of the first find call instead.

```
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
```

This isn't portable, as `alloca` isn't a standard library function and might not exist (or might be called something different) on a platform. Maybe creating a string of the appropriate length would be better: `auto message = std::string(length, '\0');`

```
    glLinkProgram(Program_id);
```

After linking the shader program, we can also detach the shader objects from the program with `glDetachShader`. This doesn't affect the linked program, and allows the shader objects to be cleaned up completely by the GL.